# symfony: Segfault while cleaning cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching, debian

I'm getting segfaults while trying to clear cache.

`app/console cache:clear --env=prod` results in 
`kernel: [44767785.874677] php[2564]: segfault at 7fff7fd76f90 ip 0000000000710a9d sp 00007fff7fd76f60 error 6 in php5[400000+893000]`

**edit**

It fails on warming up the cache.

**edit2**
[Here](http://pastebin.com/f4CWX9pd) is a strace log excerpt. I tried to make some sense of it but failed miserably.

And [here](http://pastebin.com/4vM13veS) is a strace report.

I'm running Wheezy and php 5.6 w/ Zend OPcache.

Comment: If you have `xdebug` installed, you can try to use it at first glance: `php -d xdebug.auto_trace=ON -d xdebug.trace_output_dir=. app/console cache:clear --env=prod` if it doesn't work, try to use `gdb`

Comment: … or `strace app/console cache:clear`.